# Fixing path issues on php application

Tags: centos, php5, apache2

I've installed a2billing. The problem is that it's showing only blank pages. 
Here is the apache log:

```
[Sun Oct 23 17:51:17 2016] [error] [clientIP ADDRESS] PHP Warning:  include(../lib/admin.defines.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/a2billing/admin/Public/index.php on line 34
[Sun Oct 23 17:51:17 2016] [error] [client IP ADDRESS] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../lib/admin.defines.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/a2billing/admin/Public/index.php on line 34
```

Here is the code for index.php:

```
//LICENSE HERE

include '../lib/admin.defines.php';
include '../lib/admin.smarty.php';

getpost_ifset(array (
    'error'
));

$smarty -> assign("error", $error);
$smarty -> display('index.tpl');
```

The error is obvius from here. The location of the lib directory is like follow:

```
/var/www/html/a2billing/common/lib
```

and the location of the index.php file is like this:

```
/var/www/html/a2billig/admin/Public/index.php
```

If I copy the lib directory in /var/www/html/a2billing/admin, and a few other directories, the error disappears and everything is working properly, another solution that I manage to find is if I put the full path in the include statement. However I'm having problems with those solution. For the first one the software is saying that I've change the copyright agreement and their name etc.. and that I can buy some license and they will allow me to do this. The problem with the second solution is that I can only get to display the login page, nothing else. The server has php 5.3, apache 2.2.15 and centos 6.6

Any ideas how to solve this problem, except buying license.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'common/lib/admin.defines.php'
```

also, check the permission of your application is 775, make sure that the owner and group is apache